# How to setup and run cucumber bdd test for android project in intellij 13.1.4 using cucumber-java

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

Intellij IDE supports cucumber natively. But the problem is I am trying to create and run a cucumber test on an android projects in intellij 13.1.4 IDE.
After much research I came across [this](http://www.opencredo.com/2014/01/28/cucumber-android-vs-cucumber-appium/) tutorial. But after following it and running my test I get this results

```
Running tests
Test running 
startedTest 
running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.test.cucumbertest.apptest/cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentation}
Empty test suite.
```

This is the structure of my project

    `CucumberTest
      | app
          | libs
             |
             | cucumber-android-1.1.8.jar
             | cucumber-core-1.1.8.jar
             | cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar
             | cucumber-java-1.1.8.jar
             | gherkin-2.11.2.jar
             | junit-4.11.jar
            src
             | androidTest
             |      | java
             |          | com.test.cucumbertest.app
             |                    | MyStepsDefs.java
             |                    | RunTest.java
             |                    | testclass.feature
             | main
                 | java
                     | com.test.cucumbertest.app
                                 | MainActivity.java`

MyStepDefs.java

```
package com.test.cucumbertest.app;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class MyStepDefs extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>{
    public MyStepDefs() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }
    @Given("^I have lunch the app$")
    public void I_have_lunch_the_app() throws Throwable {
        // Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
        assertTrue(true);
    } 

}
```

RunTest.java:

```
package com.test.cucumbertest.app;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = {"pretty", "html:report"})
public class RunTest {

}
```

testclass.feature:

```
Feature: Test BDD
  Scenario: Scenario One
    Given I have lunch the app
```

What am i doing wrong?

this is my AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.cucumbertest.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.cucumbertest.app.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am using gradle

Answer (score 1):

I was prompt similar messages as you provided. The different is I use Android Studio.
You can try to add instrumentation tag into your AndroidManifest.xml by

```
<instrumentation
        android:name="cucumber.api.android.CucumberInstrumentation"
        android:targetPackage="com.test.cucumbertest.app"
/>
```

However, I guess you have typo in your posted message ??("com.test.cucumbertest.apptest" => "com.test.cucumbertest.app.test")

If error still prompt, you may also need to rename your test package to "com.test.cucumbertest.app.test"